# How to fix the issue of output file not appearing, after having launched a run configuration?

Tags: optimization, cplex, opl

I work on CVRP in combinatorial optimization, where the goal is to compare several models on several instances, using the OPL language. For this to e done, I first wrote and tested the said models; then I wrote an main flow control supposed to run each instance for a 2 hours duration.
My problem is that after 2 hours, and this for each model, the output file appears for some instances, containing the desired information; but for other instances, the output files do not appear, as if these instances do not exist. This problem persists even when you launch one or more of these instances in isolation.

below is the main flow control code, where BPF designates the name of the .mod file, which is simply modified in the code, when one wishes to switch to another model.

```
{string} datFiles=...; 
main {
      var source = new IloOplModelSource("BPF.mod");
      var cplex = new IloCplex();
      var def = new IloOplModelDefinition(source);
cplex.tilim=2*60*60;
cplex.threads=1;
      for(var datFile in thisOplModel.datFiles)
      {
      var opl = new IloOplModel(def,cplex);

      var data2= new IloOplDataSource(datFile);

      opl.addDataSource(data2);
      opl.generate();
      var o=new IloOplOutputFile("BPF "+datFile+".txt");
      if (cplex.solve()) {  
      if(cplex.getCplexStatus()==11){
         o.writeln("instance : " + datFile
         +" / opt = "
         + " / UB = " + cplex.getObjValue()
          + " / LB = " + cplex.getBestObjValue()
          +" / time = " + " - "
          +" / Gap = "+cplex.getMIPRelativeGap()*100+"%"); 
              
          } 
         else {
         o.writeln("instance : " + datFile
          + " / opt = " + cplex.getObjValue()
          
          + " / UB = " + cplex.getBestObjValue()+"*"
          
          +" / time = " + cplex.getSolvedTime()
          + " / Gap : -");
        } 
        o.close();         
      }
     opl.end();
    }  
   }
```

Comment: In order to have other users help you,  you should send all model and data so that other users could try by themselves

Comment: Thanks for having replied. I have read your comment and I face some problems while transferring them. It is said: "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details." Probably because of the code's length. Could you give me a way to sort this problem out?